# Data is not deleted after docker container and volume is deleted

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have a Docker Compose setup which is supposed to just create a database using a volume I created earlier.  If I delete everything and start fresh (image, container, volume) I will see in the logs that database x can't be found.

Where is docker getting this data?  How do I make sure whenever I fire up a new Docker container it gets the data from the volume I set up and not from some other files?

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  postgresql:
    image: postgres:9.6
    restart: always
    container_name: "pgc"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=test
    ports:
     - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
     - pgvol:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
    pgvol:
     external: true
```

Comment: How about delete every containers and volumes and try only "volumes:
    pgvol:" without external: true , docker should create automatically and reuse the volume

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you want to create volume manually at all.
If you use only

```
volumes:
    pgvol:
```

docker will create volumes for you and it will reuse it.

Otherise, if you want to create manually, make sure the volume exists with the desired name

```
docker volume ls
```

which is **pgvol** in your case, to create

```
docker volume create pgvol
```

Comment: The issue is resolved, what happened is pgAdmin was open and the error was that postgres was not able to find the database pgAdmin is looking at !!